# How to add a calculated column to Access via SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ddl

How do i add a calculated column to an Access table in SQL?

I know i can add a column with SQL like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Clients ADD COLUMN AccountDate TEXT(60)
```

Thanks,
Vítor

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Seems like a fair question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add a calculated column with SQL because calculated field requires an expression and that cannot be supplied through SQL. Technically, a calculated field is a base type - int, double, text etc. Above the base type is an expression that helps Access do the math/logic.

**You could use VBA to create a calculated column**

```
-- create a module and let's assume that
-- your table has Field1 integer and Field2 integer
-- we will add field3

Public Sub CreateField()

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim TableDef As DAO.TableDef
    Dim Fld As DAO.Field2

    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set TableDef = DB.TableDefs("Table1")

    Set Fld = TableDef.CreateField("field3", dbDouble)
    Fld.Expression = "[field1] * [field2]"
    TableDef.Fields.Append Fld

    MsgBox "Added"

End Sub
```

As Gordon and BJones mentioned, you could create a view or saved query with relevant calculation.

Comment: Good point, that's true. I was earlier going to use ADO to do this, and then just did it with DAO. I'll edit the answer and remove the note regarding references.

Comment: You are right! I didn't realize until now that ADO or ADOX do not have support for addition of calculated column. Thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 2):

I don't think MS Access supports computed columns.  Instead, you can create a view:

```
create view v_clients as
    select c.*, (col1 + col2) as col3
    from clients;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to calculate? Have you tried something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Clients 
ADD COLUMN AccountDate AS (Column1 * Column2);
```

Comment: I have. I does work like that on SQL Server, but in Access i get a Syntax Error on the "As" part.

Comment: I do know that you can save a query as a table. Maybe it would be appropriate to save a query with calculated values as a table that you can view.