# Update Sum GroupBy

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, sum, vba

No of table: 1

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Total
+10     0   Prod1 
0     -10   Prod1
0     -20   Prod2
+20    0    Prod2
```

I want -

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Total
+10     0   Prod1  0
0     -10   Prod1  0
0     -20   Prod2  0
+20    0    Prod2  0
```

I want to sum col1 & col2 for the same products in Col3 in Total col.
How do I achieve this?

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.Total = (Select Sum(Table1.Total) from Table1 Group By Table1.Col3)"

Please note I am not simply adding 2 columns here. Its equivalent to SumIf of Excel that I am aiming for.

Comment: Why would you need a `SUM` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a calculated column to Access via SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621363/how-to-add-a-calculated-column-to-access-via-sql)

Comment: My aim is to get rid of zeros from the Total col. To achieve this I need to sum group by and then update this in the total col. Thanks.

Comment: I guess, we all have almost the same solution to provide :D

Answer (score 1):

You query may looks like this:

```
Select coalesce(Sum(Table1.Col1),0) + Coalesce(Sum(Table1.Col2),0)
   from Table1 
   Group By Table1.Col3
```

With `coalesce` we make sure one of `sum` will not `null`.

With `update` part:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 SET t1.Total = (
    Select coalesce(Sum(t2.Col1),0) + Coalesce(Sum(t2.Col2),0)
       from Table1 t2 
       where t2.Col3=t1.Col3
       Group By t2.Col3 
    )
```

Comment: Why? This should work. Maybe there are some vba limitations?

Comment: Of course this is only the `select` part of query. You should add `update` part by yourself

Comment: Thanks Evgeny.
I am getting error 3085 - Undefined function Coalesce

Comment: Ok, probably `vba` doesn't have this function. If you sure that `sum` can not be `null` then you can remove `coalesce`. Just leave `Select Sum(t2.Col1) + Sum(t2.Col2)`

Comment: Doesnt work either unfortunately! Wish Excel was as big as Access! I could have done in seconds

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
       (select sum(tt1.col1) + sum(tt1.col2)
        from table1 as tt1
        where tt1.col3 = t1.col3
       ) as Total
from table1 as t1;
```

If you want to do this as an `update`, it is the same idea:

```
update table1
    set Total = (select sum(tt1.col1) + sum(tt1.col2)
                 from table1 as tt1
                 where tt1.col3 = table1.col3
                );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. 
I am getting run time error 3073 if I use your code "Operation must use an updateable query"