# "Syntax error in field definition." when trying to create a computed column

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a computed column in my Access Database using C#. When running the following code I get the error

> Syntax error in field definition.

on line 4.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=database1.accdb");
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE Tabelle1 ADD Test as Skill1 + Skill2 PERSISTED", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` looks erroneous. What does `Skill1 + Skill2` even mean?

Comment: I'm not aware that MS Access supported computed columns in tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff has replied on this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621363/how-to-add-a-calculated-column-to-access-via-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think MS Access supported computed columns.  In SQL Server, you would do:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabelle1 ADD Test as (Skill1 + Skill2) PERSISTED
```

One approach in MS Access is to use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_Tabelle1 as
    SELECT t.*, (Skill1 + Skill2) as Test
    FROM Tabelle1 t;
```

Or switch to database that does support computed columns.

Comment: MS Access certainly does support computed columns. They're called _calculated fields_, see [Office support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3). I don't think there's DDL support, though.